# Change format of sap.m.Text component from the view

Tags: sapui5

I can quite handily change a button in the view using it's property 'type' in an expression..

```
 type="{= (${Orders>SupplierNote} &amp;&amp; ${Orders>SupplierNote} !== '') ?     
'Reject' : (${Orders>InternalNote} &amp;&amp; ${Orders>InternalNote} !== '') ? 
'Emphasized' : 'Default'}"/>
```

The problem is, how do I do this for a Text component?

I can't overwrite the class and it doesn't have a type.

Comment: How exactly did you want the Text to be formatted? In Bold? Italic? Bigger? Different semantic color? What was the use case? There could've been another Text-like control which supports exactly what you need. IMHO, adding a custom style class should be always the last choice, let alone adding a custom data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quit understandable that the Text control does not have something like the type property. In the context of a Button it has a clear semantic (Accept, Reject, ...) while it would be hard to achieve the same for a Text control. However, the type of a Button is just used by the renderer to apply a specific style class. You can do something similar with a Text as well:

```
<Text class="customStyleClass" text="Hellow World!"/>
```

Now your custom style class is applied. Unfortunately expression binding does not work here. If you need to make the style dependent on your data you can [write](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/1ef9fefa2a574735957dcf52502ab8d0.html) custom data to DOM and use it in your custom style class. However, this should be used sparsely.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I implemented CustomData to add a class with expression Binding...

In the View....

```
  <Text text="{Orders>EmailAddress}" tooltip="{Orders>EmailAddress}">
      <customData>
         <core:CustomData key="mydata" value="{=     (${Orders>Status} === '2' ) ? 'Red' : (${Orders>Status} === '1') ? 'Green' : (${Orders>Status} === '0') ? 'Amber' : ''}" writeToDom="true" />
      </customData>
  </Text>
```

Now the CSS.....

```
.sapMText[data-mydata="Red"] {
    color:#cc1919;
}

.sapMText[data-mydata="Green"] {
    color:#007833;
}

.sapMText[data-mydata="Amber"] {
    color:#d14900;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I recommended. So please accept or at least refer to the answer.

Comment: Ok no problem. You didn't go into detail though!

Comment: Yep, but the provided information and the link should be sufficient. :)

Comment: It looks like you wanted to give the Text a semantic color depending on certain status. Wouldn't [sap.m.ObjectStatus](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.ObjectStatus/preview) have been sufficient for that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use two text controls, each carrying one of your class options, then use conditional control on the visible attribute.

```
<Text class="customStyleClass_1" text="Hellow World!" visible="{= ${somevalue} > '0' ? false : true }"/>

<Text class="customStyleClass_2" text="Hellow World!" visible="{= ${somevalue} > '0' ? true : false }"/>
```

There are weaknesses in this approach, for example the overhead if there are many such text controls, and also if you have to refer to the text on code then you would need to determine the visible version etc.